# Ofbiz hot-deploy not firing

Tags: deployment, ofbiz, hotdeploy

I added an ofbiz component in the hot-deploy folder. 
This is a working component (fired it in the browser and all works just fine). However, after inspecting the documentation I would expect the ofbiz run-time environment to identify the new changes in java files and fire a hot deploy for the newly changed component.

I also added in **ofbiz_home/framework/base/config/ofbiz-containers.xml** the following property:

```
<property name="apps-context-reloadable" value="false"/>
```

Despite all this, the hot-deploy is not fired and I have to stop and restart the whole ofbiz application in order to see the changes made in the java files.
What am I missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hot-deploy means it doesn't require you adding the component to a component-load.xml as in applications and framework folders. If you change java files, you still have build the component and restart OFBiz. It will pick up xml and ftl files though, you might have to clean the cache, that's all.

Comment: Ok I understand that but what would it be the difference between an `application` component and a `hot-deploy` component if they both require an OFBiz restart?. I was under the impression that the `hot-deploy` component are a little bit more developer friendly.